# Having problems adding double digit number in JavaScript calculator

Tags: javascript, html, css, calculator

I can add single digits but I cannot add double digits. In this if statement, the split method helps to single out the numbers but not double digit numbers.

```
if(e.value == '='){
    var all = display.value.split("")
    number1 = parseFloat(all[0])
    operation = all[1]
    number2 = parseInt(all[2])
```

Switch statement for operations:

```
let result
    switch(operation){
      case '+':
        console.log('plus')
        result = number1 + number2
        display.value = result
    }
```

HTML:

```
<input type="button" onclick='somefunction' value="3">
<input type="button" onclick='somefunction' value="+">
```

Comment: i am not sure exactly i know it has something to do with the split method. like i can only do single digits numbers but not double digits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
var all = display.value.split("")
```

to

```
var all = display.value.replace(/ *([\+\-\*\/]) */g, ' $1 ').split(' ');
```

Basically put spaces before and after operators then split on spaces. That way numbers with multiple digits won't be split up.

[Regular expression visualization](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=g&re=%5B%20%5D*(%5B%5C%2B%5C-%5C*%5C%2F%5D)%5B%20%5D*)

Comment: you my friend are a legend!

Comment: let me know im reading this correctly. replace all the operands with $1? but what does $1 mean? sorry im new to javascript

Comment: This is regular expressions. The part between parentheses is the "matched" part. The `$1` is the placeholder for the first (and in this case only) matched part. So we are saying match any operator and replace it with space followed by that operator followed by space.

Comment: One more thing, what do the stars mean of represent? Cuz we have g so I’m confused on the importance of the stars. And why did you put them in ( )

Comment: The stars mean "any number of characters matching the character set defined to the left" so " *" (space, star) means "any number of spaces". The reason for the `()` is because that specifies which group of characters will replace `$1` in the result. Here is a [visualization](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5Cs*(%5B%5C%2B%5C-%5C*%5C%2F%5D)%5Cs*)

Comment: The `g` at the end means the whole pattern should be matched as many times as it's found. It does not mean each part of the pattern can be matched any number of times.